# Как снять деньги с подключенного аккаунта Stripe на php?

Tags: php, stripe, stripe-payments

Есть аккаунт в страйпе, у которого мне надо снять деньги и перенести на основной баланс страйпа с помощью api php. Кто работал со страйпом, помогите, пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]